# Custom Dialog constructor

Tags: java, android, interface, dialog

My interface:

```
public interface LoginDialogDismissListener {
    void loginDialogCancel();
    void loginDialogSuccess();
}
```

My activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LoginDialogDimissListener {
    public void loginDialogCancel() {
        //do stuff here     
    }

    public void loginDialogSuccess() {
        //do some other stuff here!
    }
}
```

My LoginDialog:

```
public class LoginDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener, LoginChecker {

    private ProgressBar pbLogin;
    private TextView tvLoginstatus;
    private Button cancel;
    private Button save;
    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;

    public LoginDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_dialog);
        pbLogin = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarLogin);
        tvLoginstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialogTvLoginstatus);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDialogCancel);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDialogSave);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogEtUsername);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogEtPassword);

        setTitle("Brukerdata");
        pbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tvLoginstatus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        save.setOnClickListener(this);
        //setOnDismissListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.bDialogSave) {
            saveClick();
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.bDialogCancel) {
            cancelClick();
        }
    }

    private void saveClick() {
        save.setEnabled(false);
        String[] credentials = {username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()};
        pbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        CheckLoginTask logintask = new CheckLoginTask(this, credentials, 0);
        logintask.execute();
    }

    private void cancelClick() {
        this.dismiss();
        //Here I want to call LoginDialogDismissListener.loginDialogCancel()
    }

    //Called from my AsyncTask (CheckLoginTask)
    public void onLoginSuccess(int requestCode) {
        this.dismiss();
        //Here I want to call LoginDialogDismissListener.loginDialogSuccess()
    }

    //Called from my AsyncTask (CheckLoginTask)
    public void onLoginFail(int requestCode) {
        pbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tvLoginstatus.setText("Feil brukernavn/passord ...");
        tvLoginstatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        save.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

If you have read my comments in the code, you see that I want to call my MainActivity with the methods it implements from my interface. The thing is that I can't figure out how to send my activity only *once* to my LoginDialog.

I mean, first it needs the Context, second I would like to provide it LoginDialogDismissListener (should probably change that name...), which is my activity.

I feel there is a better solution than this:

```
//Constructor
public LoginDialog(Context context, LoginDialogDismissListener listener) {
}

//Activity creating the Dialog
new LoginDialog(this, this);
```

I have tried to define the constructor to only have `LoginDialogDismissListener` as argument, but I am not allowed to cast it or somehow get the context that I need for my `super(context)`

Comment: There is use for this Dialog from other Activities

Answer (score 0):

Answer from #android-dev

Make a parent Activity that implements my interface and have all activities extend that again.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use "this", use getApplicationContext().

Comment: Don't have access to that method from my Dialog

Comment: No i mean pass it the applicationContext() in the new LoginDialog(this,this);